# Exchange disjunctions for conjunctions in a CNF formula

Tags: logic

If I have a function $\mathrm{exchange} \colon PL \to PL$
such that:

if $\varphi \in CNF$, then $\mathrm{exchange}(\varphi)$  is the result of exchange $\wedge$ for $\vee$, $\vee$ for $\wedge$, $\bot$ for $\top$, $\top$ for $\bot$, y $\ell$ for $\lnot{\ell}$ in the formula $\varphi$.

what can i say about $\mathrm{exchange}(\varphi)$, is in DNF?

Comment: If "what can I say about exchange$(\varphi)$" was meant as a separate question from "is [it] in DNF", then one of the things you can say is that  exchange$(\varphi)$ is logically equivalent to $\neg\varphi$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you swap $\land$'s and $\lor$'s, $\bot$'s and $\top$'s, and every literal with its complement, then if the original is in CNF, then the result is in DNF ... and vice versa of course!

Proof: if a statement is in CNF, then it is a conjunction of disjunctions of literals, and making the swappings as indicated, the result will be a disjunction of conjunctions of literals, and hence it is in DNF.